# Use of TypeSet vs TypeList in Terraform when building a custom provider

Tags: terraform

I'm developing a terraform provider by following [this guide](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/provider-setup).

However I stumbled upon using *TypeList* vs *TypeSet*:

> TypeSet implements set behavior and is used to represent an unordered collection of items, meaning that their ordering specified does not need to be consistent, and the ordering itself has no impact on the behavior of the resource.

> TypeList is used to represent an ordered collection of items, where the order the items are presented can impact the behavior of the resource being modeled. An example of ordered items would be network routing rules, where rules are examined in the order they are given until a match is found. The items are all of the same type defined by the Elem property.

My resource require one of 2 blocks to be present, i.e.:

```
resource "foo" "example" {
   name = "123"
   # Only one of basketball / football are expected to be present
   basketball {
      nba_id = "23"
   }
   football {
      nfl_id = "1"
   }
}
```

and my schema looks the following:

```
Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
    "name": {
        Type:        schema.TypeString,
    },
    "basketball":    basketballSchema(),
    "football":      footballSchema(),
},

func basketballSchema() *schema.Schema {
    return &schema.Schema{
        Type:     schema.TypeList,
        Optional: true,
        MaxItems: 1,
        Elem: &schema.Resource{
            Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
                "nba_id": {
                    Type:         schema.TypeString,
                    Required:     true,
                },
            },
        },
        ExactlyOneOf: ["basketball", "football"],
    }
}

func footballSchema() *schema.Schema {
    return &schema.Schema{
        Type:     schema.TypeList,
        Optional: true,
        MaxItems: 1,
        Elem: &schema.Resource{
            Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
                "nfl_id": {
                    Type:         schema.TypeString,
                    Required:     true,
                },
            },
        },
        ExactlyOneOf: ["basketball", "football"],
    }
}
```

Is that accurate that both *TypeSet* and *TypeList* will work in this scenario where we restrict the number of elements to either 0 or just 1?

Comment: Why do you need a list or a set there? the sample resource you show has no list, I would not complicate things just use `nba_id` and the `nfl_id` without the `"basketball", "football"` I don't really see a need for that